# Famous examples of one mic drum recording in pop/rock music?

Tags: recording

I have read [here](http://drummagazine.com/minimalist-drum-miking-techniques/) that the drums in Led Zeppelin's "When The Levee Breaks" were recorded with only two microphones.

But are there also famous examples of pop/rock songs, where the drums were recorded using only one microphone?

Comment: There are many examples of songs with one mic on the whole orchestra. Anything before about 1950 would probably qualify.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was actually thinking of pop/rock examples. I shall clarify my question.

Comment: The Beatles famously had to order specially, a second mic for the kit - but I have that only anecdotally, so can't make an answer.

Comment: depends on what you mean by "pop/rock". a lot of black metal recordings, and other genres that tend towards lo-fi aesthetics, have the entire band on one microphone; theyre stretching the definition of "pop", but theyre pretty clearly "rock" recordings in at least one sense of the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking in logic steps..One Mic drum technique was a really "cheap" technique for late 60's & early 70's . The music business was at its best so why not spare another Mic in there.

So as far as famous pop/rock songs (or examples) i think that it could only be used as an effect cause big studios = famous tracks.

So , two? yea , a lot .. One? hmmm.

The only reason someone would record a drum kit or even a full band with a single Mic (in the 60's - 70's era) would be because he couldn't afford more. It wasn't exactly the time of stray bootlegs or published demos that got famous hand by hand. At that time if you had something good , you were in a good studio.

On the other hand , there were a lot 1 source drum printing(2+ mics into 1 mono track) which someone could argue its similar to a single Mic setup , but if you are only after the "famous 1 Mic 60's - 70's pop/rock songs' this part doesn't interest you.

Your best bet is going back to old soul & R&B records as this guy here says:[Gabriel Roth - Minimalist Engineering](http://www.soundonsound.com/people/gabriel-roth-recording-daptone-records) (still not pop/rock but close :D)

P.S.: This is not a reference answer , it's based on my own extensive research on production and recording techniques in the older eras.